# java library for cross-database retrieval

Tags: java, hibernate, cross-database

We need to retrieve data that is spread across 3 databases (db2, sql server and as400). Is there any java library that would seamlessly and with good performance allow to "join" across tables in different databases.
What I mean by "join" is that it would be intelligent enough to query one DB and get just the keys that will be used to query the other DB and then assemble all data together. I don't want to retrieve thousands of not useful rows and iterate through to find out what should I query in other databases (as the current implementation we have now). Maybe there's something that integrates easily with hibernate.